# Where are evince bookmarks stored?

Tags: evince, pdf-bookmarks

Evince has the option to add bookmarks. My question is simple?

Where is the information about bookmarks stored?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All evince bookmarks are stored as GIO metadata under `$HOME/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`.

You can view all stored metadata for a specific file with

```
gvfs-info -a "metadata::evince::bookmarks" <document-uri>
```

References:

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2011-August/msg00000.html

Comment: Is it possible to edit them? Like renaming?

Comment: Yes, enable Side Pane (F9), then choose from the drop-down arrow **Bookmarks**. When you add a new bookmark it will appear in the list. To rename select the name and click again, you should be able to rename it now.

Answer (score 8):

I had an issue applying [Glutanimate's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/294298/). When I tested it, `gvfs-info` was not working. Some Google research led me to the conclusion that it is because `gvfs-info` has been abandoned in favor of `gio`.

So please try instead:

```
gio info -a "metadata::evince::bookmarks" <file>
```

Comment: It is not clear for me what you mean exactly. Are you saying that you tried Glutanimate's answer and it didn't work, but the command you posted worked?

Comment: Yes when I tested it `gvfs-info` was not working some google research led me that it is because that has been abandoned in favor of `gio`. This is purely for future googler's who may run into similar issue as this is 6yr old

Comment: I edited your answer to include your comment, since this information is helpful. Also I added reference to the above answer, since it might not always be above yours. And +1.

Comment: I also think that adding a reference for the replacement of `gvfs-info` by `gio` would further improve the answer.