# How can I reset Document Viewer's per-document settings?

Tags: settings, evince

Document Viewer appears to remember my settings (scroll position, zoom, full-screen, etc.) for each document. I've recently [changed its default settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400143/how-can-i-stop-document-viewer-from-always-opening-full-screen#comment513259_400143) and I want them to apply to all documents, including those I've opened previously.

How can I make it forget all per-document settings without reverting the changes I've made to the default settings?

Comment: In theory it should be in `~/.gnome2/evince`, but I can't find the folder on my PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all GVFS attributes, related to evince, for a given file with this script:

```
file="MyFile.pdf"
while read attribute value; do
    [ "${attribute:0:18}" = "metadata::evince::" ] && \
            gvfs-set-attribute "${file}" -t unset "${attribute:0:-1}"
done < <(gvfs-info "${file}")
```

You can check the attributes with `gvfs-info "${file}"`

Comment: seems like the gvfs tools have been deprecated in favor of gio. this works for me on Ubuntu 22.04: `gio info --attributes=metadata:: example.pdf | grep evince | cut -d : -f 1-5 | tr -d ' ' | xargs -L 1 gio set -t unset example.pdf`

Comment: [[ "${attribute:0:18}" =~ "metadata::atril::" ]] && gio set --type='unset' "${file}" "${attribute:0:-1}"

Comment: How does one remove evince's attributes for all files stored in gvfs's database?

Comment: @WGRM I think you mean `${attribute:0:17}`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164551/how-to-reset-all-per-folder-view-settings-in-nautilus) should work in this case as well. However: This will also delete any other type of file metadata stored by `gvfs`. Unfortunately I don't know how to remove evince metadata only.

Other relevant Q&As:

- [Where are evince bookmarks stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294285/where-are-evince-bookmarks-stored)
- [How to delete an annotation in Evince?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95042/how-to-delete-an-annotation-in-evince)

Answer (score 2):

```
gvfs-set-attribute your.pdf metadata::evince::sizing_mode "fit-width"
```

Comment: Try expanding on this